# Else statement always executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My function is always running the else statement even when it apparently satisfies the if statement. Answer is a text.get() return from a tkinter textbox.

```
def A1Next(Answer):
    print(Answer)
    Answer = str(Answer)
    if Answer == str('print("Hello World!")') or Answer == str("print('Hello World!')"):
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Edit: Below is the code segment that feeds the function, the user is answering the question "What is the command to print 'Hello World!' in python 3.4.4?"

```
Q1Title = ttk.Label(Quframe, text = "Question 1", font = ('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
Q1Title.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 3, stick = 'nsew', padx = 10, pady = 10)
Q1Label = ttk.Label(Quframe, text = "What is the command to print 'Hello World!' in python 3.4.4?", font = ('Helvetica', 10, 'bold')) ##Question user must answer
Q1Label.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 3, stick = 'nsew', padx = 10, pady = 10)
# Text box in Window 1
Q1Instructlabel = ttk.Label(Resframe, text = "Enter response below", font = ('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
Q1Instructlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, stick = 'nesw', padx = 10, pady = 10)
Answer1 = Text(Resframe, width = 40, height = 10)
Answer1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 3, stick = 'nsew', padx = 10, pady = 10)
Quitbutton = ttk.Button(Menuframe, text = "Cancel", command = lambda: Window1.destroy()) #Back and next buttons
Quitbutton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 1, stick = 'nsew', padx = 10, pady = 10)
Nextbutton = ttk.Button(Menuframe, text = "Next", command = lambda: A1Next(Answer1.get("1.0", "end"))) #Passes Info to function
Nextbutton.grid(row = 0, column = 3, columnspan = 1, stick = 'nsew', padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

Comment: The `str()` call is not needed, because `'...'` is of type `str` already. All calls to `str()` can be removed.

Comment: Also, both checks in the `if` are the same.

Comment: Try `print()`ing the value passed into the function. What is it?

Comment: @EthanK - He did.  Second line.

Comment: @MauriceReeves, yes, but I don't know what the value is. I want the OP to tell **me** the value passed in.

Comment: Does the answer really contain the function call `print()` around the message?

Comment: Your function prints Correct for this function call; A1Next('print("Hello World!")')

Comment: @EthanK ah, got you.  my bad.

Comment: @thegaminja - Can you show us the code calling this function?  What's your unit test look like?

Comment: Just edited the question to include the context for the function call. The reason why both if checks are present is if the user uses double or single quotes within their answer.

Comment: @MauriceReeves ^^^

Comment: @EthanK ^^^ here is the context.

Answer (score 1):

`Answer1.get("1.0", "end")` will return a value terminated with a newline. The values you are comparing it to don’t end in a newline so the comparison will always fail.